# How is the role of ethylene in ripening demonstrated in biology (or agriculture) education?

Tags: plant-physiology, lab-techniques

I want to know what are some typical experiments performed in the course of biology education (or possibly in applied biology education e.g. agricutlure education) to prove to the students (or have them prove to themselves) the [autocatalytic role that ethylene plays in ripening](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4677914/). I'm interested in both how ethylene production by plants might be demonstrated/measured as well as the demonstration of the role of ethylene on ripening.

I'm aware of some historical experiments e.g. that of [Gane (1934)](https://www.nature.com/articles/1341008a0). Is it commonly repeated in biology labs in an educational context today? Or is something else used?

I found a [lab manual aimed at Indian "class XII"](https://books.google.com/books?id=2QU_DAAAQBAJ&pg=PA101&dq=ethylene+fruit+lab+experiment&hl=en) (I guess that's the terminal year in high-school over there); the experiments aren't well detailed but they suggest keeping a sample in open and one packed in polyethylene, or treating one with ethylene. These aren't exactly quantitative though: no suggestions for measuring anything but by eyeballing/tasting. I guess that's the best on can do with limited resources. I'd like to know about college-level experiments, if there are any.

I also know how ethylene is [measured in industrial/pro-lab settings](https://books.google.com/books?id=2BKcCgAAQBAJ):

> Ethylene
>   can be measured successfully with a portable gas chromatograph fitted with a
>   photo ionisation detector capable of measuring ethylene to a concentration below
>   0.01 uL/L. EASI-1 uses a proprietary ‘nanoporous gold sensor technology’ for
>   “accurate real-time measurement of ethylene gas concentrations”. This is licensed
>   from Fluid Analytics in USA, which offers a claimed sensitivity to ethylene in
>   the air at levels as low as 10 ppb.

There also exist industrial scrubbers for ethylene so the air concentration can be reduced. I don't know if either of these are commonly available on college campuses though, even in biotech or agriculture departments.

(N.B.: I don't care about proving the effect in the kitchen, which is the [topic of a question on Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/42025/do-certain-fruit-combinations-ripen-faster).)

Comment: One way (I don't know how easy it is to get hold of the compounds in your locality) would be to have three sealed containers containing apples, one in standard conditions, one in elevated ethylene, and one with 1-methylcyclopropene which competitively binds the ethylene receptor, and observe the differences in ripening rate.

Comment: As titled and phrased, this is a question that only a professional teacher could answer. Is this your intent or are you really asking for ideas of nice, compact demonstrations that could be done in a classroom?

Comment: @JimYoung: I want to know how it's done (if it is) in existing education, not for radom ideas how it could be done. And it's not just that a "professional teacher could answer". Lab manuals etc. anyone can read.

Comment: This is a Biology list, not an education list. So it's OK to ask how it was shown that ethylene has a role in ripening — although we'd expect you to show that you'd tried to find the answer yourself — but I think it's off-topic to ask how to do it in the constrained circumstances of a teaching course.

Comment: @David: really? Let me ask on meta here. Actually, it was asked already, and you seem to be wrong: https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3162/questions-about-teaching-biology-off-limits "questions that ask for ways and methods to teach specific biological concepts or techniques (lab or field) should be on-topic." (that's the only answer) Also "All questions asking for this type of advice should be narrowly defined, so that the scope of possible answers isn't too wide." Not asking about hypothetical but only about actually used methods seems to satisfy that well.

Comment: A question was asked on meta and one person replied that he thought they "can" be on-topic and seven people agreed with him. That does not define the scope of SE Biology or mean that I am wrong. The scope of SE Biology is laid out in the [Help](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and my reading of it is that it does not include questions of your type. I suggest you do some research on the subject and state what you think are the problems of repeating the experiment in the classroom. Then I and others will consider whether it is or is not off-topic.

Comment: @David: I already know of some historical experiments in general terms; see my answer on Skeptics. (The details only appear in obscure publications from the 1930s that are hard to get--not online, etc.) If I take the time to read some lab manuals myself, that would make my question here moot, unless I want to waste my time typing an answer to my own question (which seldom gets any appreciation anywhere on SE). I don't see what's wrong with my questions as-is.

Comment: I second the idea that asking a forum of biologists "which typical experiments are performed in the course of biology education" is missing the area of expertise that you can expect here. During the course of *my* education, there have been no such demonstrations, which probably answers your question on whether such demonstrations are routine in biology classes in schools around the world. I also guess most research biologists today have had no such demonstrations in school. @NatWH already has suggested an experiment, if you are interested in a specific way to demonstrate this in a classroom